# Add hourly rate to line items based on line item date

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

**Hello, I'm trying to set up a system using google forms and google sheets to keep track and analyse my business's employee's hrs and wage.**

**My idea is:**

Use a simple Google Form to for employees to submit their daily hrs. (The Name will be a dynamic list using the Form Ranger Addon which will be populated by a google sheet which has a list of all employees names.)

The Google Form will be linked to this Google Sheet which holds the columns Employee | Date | Start time | End time and then the calculated columns Total Hrs and Hourly Rate.

**This is where I get stuck!**
​
I want the Hourly Rate to be an arrayformula and to be dynamic based on the values of a different sheet. Let me explain!

Employee wages might change throughout the year and I would like the hourly rate line amount accounting to each employees daily submission to be dynamic based on the employees changing rates.

I thought to have a separate sheet where I will fill in employees hourly rate and every time the rate changes. This will look like this.

So finally:

How do i write an array formula that returns the employees hourly rate based on the date in the row (output of daily from submission)?

I was thinking some kind of nested XLOOKUP but I'm totally stuck.

Help please good people! :D

[Google Form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSf9uryZ2awZ_HNw2anmJQPcbZ9YLjzxusHYvIjQrXmm6V822w/viewform?usp=sharing) and [Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1rPSTygJqyWWhnLToQ62mR_IpQipkVQ4ncAjBXQw_HiE/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 1):

### Formula

This formula will return the hourly rate based on the date worked ignoring future increases that do not apply.

```
=LAMBDA(r, INDEX(r, XMATCH(dateWorked, INDEX(r,, 2), -1), 3))
 (SORT(FILTER(rateTable,INDEX(rateTable,, 1)=employee),2, FALSE ))
```

### Conditions

- **"dateWorked"** is the day the hours are worked (in form);
- **"rateTable"** is a 3 column range with

  1. employee names in column 1;
  2. dates in column 2 (effective date for the new hourly rate);
  3. hourly rates in column 3
- **"employee"** is the employee name (in form)

### Notes

1. LAMBDA is used to avoid repeating the initial SORT and FILTER and use **`r`** in its place
2. **"rateTable"** is filtered for the employee and then sorted in descending order by date: **`r`**
3. XMATCH is used to find the date in **`r`** that *either* matches the date worked *or* is older.
4. INDEX returns the hourly rate in the same row as the XMATCH-ed date

### BYROW Version (single formula)

This version takes the formula above and uses [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) to perform the same [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) formula for each row in the name column (column A).

- a named range **`employee`** was created `A2:A500`,
- [BYROW](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12570930) passes each row **`employee`** into a [LAMBDA](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) function where the current row is represented by the arbitrarily chosen name **`e`**
- If **`e`** is empty (no data entered) the formula is skipped: `IF(e<>"", <formula>, IFERROR(1/0)` (`IFERROR(1/0) is a sheets trick to return a genuinely blank result) ;
- to get the **"employee"** from the current row (e.g. `A2`) I can now use the **`e`** in the formula;
- for the **"dateWorked"** in the formula I can use the same **`e`** variable but use [OFFSET](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093379) to indicate where the data is located in relation to **"employee"**.  In this  **"dateWorked"** is `0 rows` and `1 column` away from the **"employee"** column: `OFFSET(e, 0 , 1)` `

```
=BYROW(employee, LAMBDA(e, 
   IF(e<>"", 
      (LAMBDA(r, INDEX(r, XMATCH(OFFSET(e,0,1), INDEX(r,, 2), -1), 3))
        (SORT(FILTER(rateTable,INDEX(rateTable,, 1)=e),2, FALSE ))),
      IFERROR(1/0))
))
```

[image]